# How to have react navigator mount again in react navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am fetching notifications inside my navigator component. The problem is that when a user logs out and logs back in, the data is wrong as its not being refetched again as the navigator component doesnt mount anymore. How can I do that? Is it not possible to fetch anything the navigator and can I only do it inside a screen component that I can unmount when user leaves it or is there any way? Thanks!

```
<React.Fragment>
     <NotificationsProvider>
           <AuthProvider>
                <Navigator onLayoutRootView={onLayoutRootView} />
           </AuthProvider>
     </NotificationsProvider>
</React.Fragment>

<NavigationContainer onReady={onLayoutRootView} ref={navigationRef}>
     <MyStack />
</NavigationContainer>
```

```
const MyStack = () => {
   useEffect(() => {
      ...
      fetching some data
      ...
   }, [])
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with react navigator.

If you want to refetch data again after an user sign-in back, you should add a credential or log-in state to a useEffect's dependency so the effect run again after the dependency changed.

```js
const MyStack = () => {
   const { isSignedIn } = useContext(AuthContext)
 
   useEffect(() => {
      ...
      fetching some data
      ...
   }, [isSignedIn])
}
```

The new React API document is really good. I recommend you to read it https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect